# Retrofit response exception

Tags: java, android

in the first case when it returns success true, everything works, the problem when it gets success boolean is false, then the error:

*Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 26 path $ .data*

Can it be done with one reponse class?

```
Json response:
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "message": "User created",
    }
}
```

```
Json response:

{
    "success": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "code": "existing_user_login",
            "message": "User Exist !"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Code:
public class Response {
    public Boolean success;
    public Data data;

    public Boolean isSuccess() { return success; }

    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public class Data {
        public String code;
        public String message;
        public String getMessage() { return message; }
        public String getCode() { return code; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In success response you are getting the object

"data": { **// object**
"message": "User created",
"id": 98
}

In failure response you are getting an array

"data": [  **//array**
{
"code": "existing_user_login",
"message": "User Exist !"
}
]

The expected failure response would be

"data":
{  // Object
"code": "existing_user_login",
"message": "User Exist !"
}

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not interfere with what I get, on success is object and false is an array, how to make an exception?

Answer (score 0):

when response is `"success": true` you have get `object` in `data`

Then when response is `"success": false` you have get `array` in `data`

This can cause you problems